# NSTextField on my UI and need to access them by tag

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tags, uitextfield, nstextfield

I have 8 NSTextFields and I need to access them by UI to determine if the NSTextField has any data. If it's empty then I mark a bool as NO and check the next field. Eventually I'll highlight all the required fields and present it to the user.

Here's my pseudocode

```
-(BOOL)isFormValid
{
for(int i=0; i< 9; i++)
{
if <tag>.text != nil or <tag>.text != @"" then
return NO
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue.
Find my solution here http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/77945-jumping-across-text-fields.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this will help:

```
[superviewOfTextFields viewWithTag:tag];
```

Comment: its a text field. not a textview.

Comment: Unimportant. Text fields also can be added as subviews. The main point is they are subclasses of NSView.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the above code. I only have 1 window. do I use [window viewWithTag:1]

Comment: If the window is the superview of the text fields, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an [`NSForm`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSForm_Class/)? As the name suggests, it's designed for text forms. You have one outlet to the form as a whole and can get each field in the form with [`cellAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSForm_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000102-BBCDADID)

[image: Screenshot of <code>NSForm</code> object in IB]

Comment: I am new to this and never realized that a form existed.

Comment: Well, that's what we're here for! :)

Comment: Would it be possible to change one of the fields to a popup?